# Saving filepicker.io uploaded picture to a mysql database

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to use the filepicker.io widget.  I would like to save the event.fbfile.url in a mysql database.  Would i use a .get with jquery to save the image url?  Code examples would be helpful.  Thank you for your help.  Below is the code widget.

```
<input name="img" data-fp-class="form-simple-action-btn filepicker_launcher" data-fp-button-text="Choose Image" data-fp-services="COMPUTER,FACEBOOK,FLICKR,INSTAGRAM,PICASA" data-fp-container="modal" data-fp-mimetypes="image/*" type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="AmKDQg1vZRBatEqkUY6Qxz" data-onchange="console.log(event.fpfile.url)" id='campaign-img-input'">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some server side code to write to your database.

If this is part of an html form, the url will appear in the form when submitted and you can save it to your db just like any other part of your form.

If this is not part of a form, you can probably set up a simple server side endpoint that you can do an ajax post to and that when you post data to the endpoint, it will save the data into your mysql.

If you provide more detail about how your system is set up and how you are currently writing to your database, I can probably be more helpful.

Comment: So I have it set up with a form; I post the event.fpfile.url (which I place in the value filed).  So I have: $filepicker = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['event.fpfile.url']);  Then I perform a query to place $filepicker in the column 'filepicker' I have to contain the url.  This is not working.  Thoughts?

Comment: So without more details, I think what you want to do is: 1. remove the  data-onchange function. 2. on your php server side page, you should see the filepicker url in $_POST['img']. (print_r is probably helpful here to print the $_POST array. You should see a field with a url that looks like "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/SOMETHING")

Comment: Hi Liyan, sorry to keep harping on this, but I am trying to make this work and I am still running into issues.  Just to clarify, you are sayin I should have in the widget: value="<php echo h($_POST['img'])" and then on server side, I can set $filepicker = $_POST['img'] to get the array that contains the url.  Then I can use $filepicker[url] to get the url itself?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy to help though I'm having a really tough time keeping track of all the moving parts. Do you mind sharing more code? Both the php that you are using to generate the html and the php you are using to process the form?